# Apollo Federation gateway and another server implementation

Tags: apollo-server, apollo-federation

I am reading about apollo federation and how to migrate from schema stitching and a question came when I read:

> The basic strategy for migrating from a stitching gateway to Apollo Federation is to start by making the underlying services federation-capable

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/migrating-from-stitching/#adding-federation-support-to-services

basically federation gateway can't accept another service not federation aware? so there's no way to use federation with another graphql server (such https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse) or should I misunderstood that line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, any GraphQL service that's incorporated into the federation gateway has to implement Apollo's [federation specification](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/federation-spec).

Federation relies on the service schema containing several specific types, directives and type extensions:

```
scalar _Any
scalar _FieldSet

union _Entity

type _Service {
  sdl: String
}

extend type Query {
  _entities(representations: [_Any!]!): [_Entity]!
  _service: _Service!
}

directive @external on FIELD_DEFINITION
directive @requires(fields: _FieldSet!) on FIELD_DEFINITION
directive @provides(fields: _FieldSet!) on FIELD_DEFINITION
directive @key(fields: _FieldSet!) on OBJECT
directive @extends on OBJECT
```

The service does not have to be a GraphQL.js implementation, but it does need to implement the above additions to the schema as outlined in the spec.

Comment: so if I add those types to a php graphql server should it work with federation gateway without any use of apollo federation package there, right?

Comment: It's not enough to just add these entities, you would also have to implement the appropriate logic for resolving the fields on the added types, and for handling the added directives and for serializing and deserializing the added scalars. What that logic looks like is described in the spec and can also be gleamed from examining the source code for `@apollo/federation`. Provided you do that, then, yes, the service should be compatible with federation.

Comment: So, where is this documented? Sounds like if the platform doesn't implement Federation you're screwed. Glad we still have stiching available.

Comment: @Marc [Here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/implementing): "To be part of a federated graph, a microservice implements the Apollo Federation spec which exposes its capabilities to tooling and the gateway." Federation is still a pretty new concept in GraphQL. Hopefully, if it catches on, other major GraphQL implementations will follow suite so that it can be used regardless of your stack.

Answer (score 1):

Like [@daniel-rearden said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56432125/9351632) it does need to implement additions to the spec.
Check out [graphql-transform-federation](https://github.com/0xR/graphql-transform-federation) to assist you with adding the required info. Also check out this [blog post](https://xebia.com/blog/graphql-federation-for-everyone/)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the server you also need to build the gateway, if you are using docker-compose you can use a reusable docker image as follows:

```
version: '3'

services:
    a:
        build: ./a # one service implementing federation
    b:
        build: ./b
    gateway:
        image: xmorse/apollo-federation-gateway
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        environment: 
            CACHE_MAX_AGE: '5' # default cache
            ENGINE_API_KEY: '...' # to connect to the apollo engine
            POLL_INTERVAL: 30 # to update services changes
            URL_0: "http://a"
            URL_1: "http://b"
```

Check out the [github repo](https://github.com/remorses/apollo-federation-gateway) for a working example.